# Getting Empty strings back - Ethereum

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I am developing E-Voting system and when I enter my Data it works fine but when I retrieve my data it return my empty strings.

**.Sol File:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract Voting{
    
    address public owner = msg.sender;

    struct AddCandidate 
    {
        string name;
        string party;
        uint age;
        string qualification;
    }

    mapping(string=>AddCandidate) candidate;

    function addMembers(string memory _name, string memory _party, uint _age, string memory _qualification) public
    {
        candidate[_name] = AddCandidate({
            name:_name,
            age:_age,
            party:_party,
            qualification:_qualification
        });
        
    }

    function showMembers(string memory name) public view returns (string memory _name, string memory _party, uint _age, string memory _qualification)
    {
        
        _name = candidate[name].name;

        _party = candidate[name].party;

        _age = candidate[name].age; 

        _qualification = candidate[name].qualification;
    }
   
}
```

**Logic of Posting Data:**

```
const postData = async () => {
    console.log("Happeneing");
    await Voting.methods.addMembers(user.name,user.party,user.age,user.qualification).call().then(success=>{
        console.log(success);
    });
}
```

**Logic of Retrieving Data:**

```
const showData = async () =>{
        await Voting.methods.showMembers(user.name).call().then(success=>{
            console.log(success);
            console.log("succedd")
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you save the data, you are using a local `call`. This kind of call does not generate a transaction and does not modify the blockchain state - it's meant only for reading data, for free.

You have to create a real transaction to modify the state for real. So instead of `call`, use `send`.

Read more about calls here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call